# How do I unmask a link from my domain masked site to an external site?

Tags: forwarding, masking

I registered domain www.a.com
I then forwarded with masking (using GoDaddy) traffic from www.a.com to www.really.long.url.com, so users will only see www.a.com in their address bar when visiting my site.
The problem, is that if a user clicks a link to www.google.com while on my website, they get directed to Google, but their address bar still reads www.a.com.

How can I disable this domain masking for external links?

Comment: This is a "how do I use GoDaddy's interface" question, not a programming question.

Comment: @Marcus - that may be, but with the right kind of answer, it can also be a "how does domain masking work, what are the drawbacks, and what should I be doing instead" question. But then I'm biased because I just tried to write such an answer and I want your vote ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Best answer would be "don't use domain masking" because it has many drawbacks including:

- The problem you have - when users leave your site via links to external sites the address bar still shows your domain.
- Different pages within your own site don't change the address bar either, so user's can't bookmark individual pages of your site
- Your favicon won't work
- Search engines will not index your content as if it belonged to `a.com`, because it doesn't - it's still being served by `really.long.url.com`
- Any RSS feeds advertised by your site will not show up in the address bar on browsers that support this

To avoid these drawbacks, you should configure the DNS for `a.com` so it and the `www` CNAME are actually pointed at your webserver, and your website can be served from `a.com` directly.

Having said that, to solve the question you asked, links to external sites from within a domain masked site should be changed to use the deprecated `target="_top"` attribute. This breaks out of the invisible frameset that GoDaddy (and others) use to implement the not-very-clever "domain masking". The source of `http://www.a.com/` basically looks something like this:

```
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://www.really.long.url.com" frameborder="0" />
</frameset>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Mys issue was - links won't open on the website once I use GoDaddy's masking "service". The target="_top" absolutely solved this issue. A short question - is there any downside for using that attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I'll just add extra data regarding the solution @Day provided:

`target="_top"` will load the entire current browser window with the url specified in the link (Effectively removing the frameset page).

**Target**:

- _blank = Link will open in new window
- _top = Link will clear any existing frames and open URL as the uppermost document
- _parent = Link will open in parent frame (if several levels deep). Equal to _top if only one level frameset
- _self = Link will open in current frame/window etc, whichever is applicable

[source: http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum21/4397.htm ]