# VIEWPORT doesn't work with an URL redirected

Tags: php, css, redirect, mobile, viewport

I have a problem using meta tag viewport.

When I enter into my website through the domain name I hired (a redirection to use a more confortable URL) the viewport meta doesn't work, but if I use the original URL (really ugly and not useful at all, that's why I have a redirection) to access into my web the viewport works, look here I paste the URLs to let you try by yourself:

- (*HERE DOESN'T WORK*) This is the redirection URL: [http://padelcniinfinit.com/tag_test.php](http://www.padelcniinfinit.com/tag_test.php)
- (*HERE WORKS*) URL real of my WEB: http://aitor.rvfcursos.com/tag_test.php

How can be possible this? Any clue about how to fix it?

thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

The kind of redirection you are using works by embedding the destination page in a frameset, you can check this by displaying the page source or inspecting it through the developers tools of your browser. It's not an actual redirection (as in `HTTP 3xx`) but a page at a nice URL which embeds your ugly-URL page.

As such, the embedded page gets an invalid viewport value.

There may be some workarounds that you can use discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778378/responsive-design-and-viewport-not-working-through-domains-frameset).