# enabling links in <frameset> issue

Tags: html, css, heroku, hyperlink, frameset

I have a problem when I'm using the *GoDaddy.com* (domain only) official option — **Mask URL**.

**I'll explain**: this feature's purpose is to "pin" the same URL to the browser when visiting the website, no matter on what page I am.

**The purpose I'm using this**: that I don't have a hosting contract yet, so I'm using *Heroku* free hosting service and that means a long and "ugly" URL address.

**The problem I'm facing**:
when entering the source code of my domain (in *Chrome* - `view-source:http://ravidgal.com/`), I see that the code that *GoDaddy* "injects" in order to perform the masking operation is:

```
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://radiant-stream-2083.herokuapp.com/" frameborder="0" />
  <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>
```

That causes — **no link on the page can be opened**.

When I enter the *Heroku* URL "manually" (http://radiant-stream-2083.herokuapp.com/) I can access the links without any problem. I'm sure the problem is with the `<frameset>`.

**My question**: How can I continue using the Mask option and still be able to open links on my page (on any browser)? I mean, I can't access and change the Mask-code *that GoDaddy* "injects". What are my options? **It's hard to believe that this Masking options won't let me open any links.**

That's how the Domain options screen look on *GoDaddy.com*:

[image]

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `target="_top"` to the link solved the issue.

Found the solution here: [How do I unmask a link from my domain masked site to an external site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210155/how-do-i-unmask-a-link-from-my-domain-masked-site-to-an-external-site?answertab=oldest#tab-top)